# Conversion from string "ACECATN000001" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net

I am a new in using asp.net i have recieving an error of "Conversion from string "ACECATN000001" to type 'Integer' is not valid." can anyone help me how to solve this?? thanks in advance :D

```
        If lbl_productcatcode.Text = "ACECATN000001" Then
            txt_productcode.Text = Format(CInt(rdr.Item(0).ToString) + 1, "1000000")

        End If
    End If
    cmd1.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: The string is alphanumeric.... and integer is numeric... What are you trying to do with that string?  You can't convert an alphanumeric into a numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You've posted some code but not said which line has the error, I presume it is this one:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "Select CategoryID from CategoryTable where ProductCategory = '" & DropDownList1.Text & "'"
```

If the `CategoryId` column on the `CategoryTable` is of type `integer`, then you cannot compare it against a string value. I would guess that you need to use the ID of the item bound to the DropdownList, IIRC there should be a SelectedValue property on the dropdown that you can use for this.

```
cmd1.CommandText = "Select CategoryID from CategoryTable where ProductCategory = " & DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

Note the absense of single quotes as you will be injecting an `int` value into the sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: `CInt(s)` converts `s`(`s` being a string) to integer and is only valid if `s` contains **only** numbers(no letters).

In this line:

```
  txt_productcode.Text = Format(CInt(rdr.Item(0).ToString) + 1, "1000000")
```

you are trying to convert `rdr.Item(0).ToString` to an integer. According to your code,
`rdr.Item(0).ToString` returns `"ACECATN000001"` which contains letters and hence cannot be converted to integer.
What exactly are u wanting to do in that line?

Comment: i want to display an autogenerate id of ACECATNOOOOO1... The scenario is like this a dropdownlist searches the category id of the product category and when the category id is generated the product code of the  category is generated too... it was like category auto generate category id and category id generate product id??? do you have any idea to do that.. i was trying to use count but i recieve error...